# How can I solve part a. of this geometric probability question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Deangelo is planning a bus ride to the airport. He can
choose between the Crimson bus, which arrives at the bus stop every $8$ minutes,
or the Gold bus, which arrives at the bus stop every $15$ minutes. He would prefer
to take the Gold bus because the bus makes fewer stops. In order to get to the
airport by a certain time, Deangelo cannot wait more than $5$ minutes without
risking being late for his flight.

$a.$ What assumption do you have to make to solve this problem?

$b.$ To the nearest percent, what is the probability that Deangelo will have to wait
5 minutes or less to see both buses?

$c.$ To the nearest percent, what is the probability that Deangelo will have to wait
5 minutes or less to see only one of the buses?

---

I know that parts b. and c. can be solved using graphs, but I don't know what to assume in part a. I just need help with the a. part.

Comment: Deangelo's preference for the Gold bus does not factor in in any of these questions ... if he can't risk being late, he needs to get on the first bus that comes, like it or not

Comment: @Bram28 What? I don't understand. I've already solved the last two parts but I don't know how to answer part a.

Comment: I was just commenting what a weird question this is ... they have this whole thing about there being 2 buses, and Deangelo preferring one bus over the other, and so it seems like they are setting up some kind of decision or optimization problem (e.g. if the Crimson bus comes at 1 minute, should Deangelo chance it and wait for the Gold bus?) ... but in the end none of that seems to matter: he needs to get his ass on the first bus that comes and that's it. Kind of a missed opportunity for a more interesting question. But yeah, you can ignore all that for your purpose :P

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag, which is for geometric problems involving probability, not for the geometric distribution. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.